# Is there a term for using conjugating verbs such that the sentence continues with another clause?

Tags: grammar, terminology, renyōkei

I'm referring specifically to using the て form to form a pseudo conjunction, and specifically the transformation of verbs in formal writing by using the verb stem instead of て form.

For example the following sentence:

> 多くの人が**押し掛け**、大騒ぎになっているという

Is there a grammatical term for this, either a verb form or some sort of usage term?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that when you use the 連用形 as a conjunction, the form is referred to as the [中止形](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%B8%AD%E6%AD%A2%E5%BD%A2).  This usage is described by [中止法](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%B8%AD%E6%AD%A2%E6%B3%95).

---

For future reference, here's the definition for 中止形 from 日本文法大辞典 (p.475):

> ### 中止形【ちゅうしけい】
>
> 連用形の中の一つで、主に中止法として用いられる形。
>
> ```
> 〔例〕花咲き、鳥歌ふ  
> 　　　空青く、雲白し  
> 　　　波静かに、風爽やかなり
> ```
>
> ただ、現代語の形容動詞には「（静か）だっ・で・に」の三形があるが特に「（静か）で」の形を中止形という（町は**静かで**、誰もいない）。中止形は二つの文を対等の資格で並べる対句の構成に多く用いられる。『方丈記』などには特にそのような形が多い。
>
> ```
> 〔例〕淀みにうかぶうたかたは、かつ消え、かつ結びて  
> 　　　たましきの都のうちに、棟をならべ、甍を争へる  
> 　　　朝に死に、夕に生るるならひ
> ```
>
> 中止形を含んだ文と、そのあとに続く文との関係は、大きく次の二つに分けられよう。
>
> ①同時に起こる事柄、または、同時に存在する状態を並列して示す。
>
> ```
> 〔例〕犬は庭をかけまわり、猫はこたつでまるくなる
> ```
>
> ②時間的な進行の順序に従って事柄を述べる。
>
> ```
> 〔例〕店に入り、本を買う
> ```
>
> そして、この②はさらに、③中止形を含んだ文が、ある条件を示して後の文に続く（「雨に**濡れ**、風邪をひく」「大声で**叫び**、助けを求める」）ということに発展することができる。しかし、中止形を含んだ文は、後に続く文との時間的な先後関係を示すというのが原則であるから、その続き方が順接であるか逆説であるかは場面によって異なってくる。
>
> ```
> 〔例〕崖から落ち、命を失った  
> 　　　崖から落ち、傷一つ負わなかった
> ```
>
> 現代語では、「店にはいっ**て**、本を買う」「雨に濡れ**て**、風邪をひく」のように、接続助詞「て」を用いるのが普通であるが、新聞の報道記事のように限られた紙面に事件・事柄を記していく場合などでは、中止形を用いることが多い。
>
> ```
> 〔例〕犯人は友達を訪れ、スキヤキを食べ、ライフルを取出し
> ```

Comment: This is correct. However, it need not be a verb. Any 用言 will suffice. (Hence, an adjective as well.)