# Can you use the base of the 〜ます form to mean "and" in spoken Japanese?

Tags: て-form, politeness, spoken-language

When written I've read that you can use the base of the 〜ます form to mean "and". But does the same rule apply when spoken?

For example, does the following sentence make sense **when spoken**?

> そしてシステムにログイン**し**、部品を探し注文します

Or should it instead be:

> そしてシステムにログイン**して**、部品を探し注文します

Comment: Check out this post: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9771/is-there-a-term-for-using-conjugating-verbs-such-that-the-sentence-continues-wit

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's fine to use that form in formal writing. But does it sound unnatural when spoken?

Comment: You are right, it may well sound starchy in speech, but it depends on the context.

Comment: Did you realize you were already using the same form in 探し?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usage is called [中止法](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9771/5010). You can use it safely in formal speech, but it's rare in casual speech. For example, a mother would almost never say 早く歯を磨き学校に行きなさい to her children.