# ~し in メキシコ湾流に漕ぎ出し、独りで漁をしていた

Tags: grammar

I'm not understanding how 〜し works in the sentence below. It seems to operating as the standard connective, but why does it affect the conjugation of 漕ぎ出す?

> 小さな船でメキシコ湾流に漕ぎ出し、独りで漁をしていた

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9772/30454

Comment: As Eddie's [linked post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9772/30454) describes, what you have here is the compound verb 漕【こ】ぎ出【だ】す ("to row out") conjugated into the 連用形【れんようけい】 ("continuative or stem form") and used conjunctively.  In Japanese education for non-native speakers, conjunctive constructions are commonly taught using the ～て form, which is (mostly) the 連用形【れんようけい】 of a verb + て.  However, the 連用形【れんようけい】 alone can be used in a conjunctive construction, which is what we have in your sample sentence.